# h2o | R parseSetup issue

Tags: r, dataframe, h2o

**Used**
R version : 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
jdk version "1.8.0_181"
H2O cluster version: 3.20.0.10 
Installed all the dependent package as mentioned in H2O documentation

```
cpu1$Average = as.numeric(as.character(cpu1$Average))
network1$Average = as.numeric(as.character(network1$Average))

cpu = cpu1$Average
network  = network1$Average

cpu = as.h2o(as.data.frame(cpu))
network = as.h2o(as.data.frame(network))
```

Input data:
         cpu
1 28.7341993
2  0.7342352
3  0.3874931
4  0.3959669
5  0.3862666
6  0.5541219

network
1 444796.4000
2  29544.5167
3    193.9333
4    359.2667
5    881.7833
6 648985.3667

```
data  = h2o.cbind(cpu,network)

# class(data) "H2OFrame"

h2o.parseSetup(data)
```

## Getting this error please advice.

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Bad Request (url = http://localhost:54321/3/ParseSetup)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 [1] "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key not loaded: Key /tmp/Rtmpq3doob/file3ff4261bfad.csv_sid_82a4_1"
 [2] "  water.api.ParseSetupHandler.guessSetup(ParseSetupHandler.java:31)"
 [3] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
 [4] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"
 [5] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
 [6] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
 [7] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:63)"
 [8] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:451)"
 [9] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:296)"
[10] "    water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:222)"
[11] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"
[12] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"
[13] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"
[14] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)"
[15] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"
[16] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)"
[17] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"
[21] "    water.JettyHTTPD$LoginHandler.handle(JettyHTTPD.java:197)"
[22] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)"
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)" 
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)"
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)"
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"
[35] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  :

ERROR MESSAGE:
Key not loaded: Key /tmp/Rtmpq3doob/file3ff4261bfad.csv_sid_82a4_1
Calls: as.h2o ... h2o.parseSetup -> .h2o.__remoteSend -> .h2o.doSafeREST
Execution halted

Comment: Please be mindful of the tags you put on questions.  Even though you may be using a JVM, the [tag:java] tag is not appropriate for this question as it is not the subject of your question.  I have untagged it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The call to parseSetup does not belong here.

as.h2o() already gave you a fully capable h2o frame.

Then binding two h2o frames gave you a third h2o frame.  You can just use it.

Comment: Yes, correct. The result I posted works well on my local desktop. But when did the same testing in the container it is giving me an error when **cpu = as.h2o(cpu)**

  
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
  

ERROR MESSAGE:

Key not loaded: Key<Frame> /tmp/Rtmp0Wrlif/file7544e612dd.csv_sid_ade6_1

Calls: as.h2o ... h2o.parseSetup -> .h2o.__remoteSend -> .h2o.doSafeREST
Execution halted

Comment: This issue has been resolved. Problem here is: I am using R 3.1.1 version which is not compatible. So I upgraded it to R 3.5.1 after which I am not facing this issue